# Effective way to change the adjacency matrix on clustering

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a 2D grid where each point that is not on the boundary has 4 nearest neighbors and we assume only those to be connected to the point. Now, a black-box algorithm outputs clusters of random points in the grid such that neighbors of any point in the cluster now become neighbors of all other points in the cluster because the "distance" to move among the points within the cluster is zero. What should be the most effective way to change the adjacency matrix of the graph corresponding to the grid after formation of clusters ? 
For example, take the grid

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

now, if 1 and 9 are clustered together, there is a 0 distance path between 1 and 9 making all neighbors of 1 (2 and 4) also neighbors of 9 and vice-versa.

I need to implement this on a much larger grid with much larger clusters. What I have right now is unfortunately brute force- taking neighbors of one point in the cluster, make them neighbors of all other points within the cluster and so on. Please let me know if anything in the question is not clear.

Comment: So you currently have an algorithm that updates the adjacency matrix, but it is O(n*n) (quadratic) in the number of points in the cluster, and you're looking for a point that is O(n) in the number of clustered points, right?

Comment: Yes, better than O(n*n)

Comment: Assuming that the number of points in the cluster is *far* lower than the total number of points, I doubt that there is a more efficient solution. The only alternative that I could think of would be: 1. Walk over the rows of the adjacency matrix that correspond to the cluster points. 2. combine them with an "OR" operation. 3. Assign the resulting row to all rows that correspond to cluster points. But processing a (large) row may be more expensive than processing the (few) cluster points.